# Export data from SQL Server to SAS Files (sas7bdat)

Tags: sql-server, sas, spss, data-export

I was tasked to find a way to export data directly from SQL Server to SAS files (*.sas7bdat), I do not have an instance of SAS installed to go that route and have been searching for hours now to find a solution.

My first approach was to find a SAS driver for SQL Server, that would have been ideal. after a long search I turned my head towards the idea of an free/opensource tool that maybe can convert csv to .sas7bdat, still no luck

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: That's a proprietary format. There's a python package and  http://www.stattransfer.com

Comment: There is also an R package that exports data to SAS: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreign/index.html

Comment: SAS can connect directly to SQL Server, if that's an option.